# How to use shapes and layer to get gradient edge?

Tags: android, gradient, layer, shapes

I want to create a seek-bar with a solid fill and the edges. I want to have a little gradient map.

The only solution I come close to is a solid color and a stroke on the edge. 
But then the stroke can't have a gradient map attached to it, or can it? Can I maybe just draw a 2nd 3rd and 4th stroke next to the one I already have?

My code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@android:id/background" >
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
                <solid android:color="#5fbcff" />
                <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#9bd0f7" />
                <padding android:left="2px" android:top="2px" android:right="2px" android:bottom="2px" />
            </shape>

        </item>
        <item android:id="@android:id/progress" >
            <clip android:clipOrientation="vertical" android:gravity="bottom" >
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
                    <solid android:color="#f0f0f0" />
                    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#9bd0f7" />
                    <padding android:left="1px" android:top="1px" android:right="1px" android:bottom="1px" />
                </shape>
            </clip>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Here is a link of how I want it to look and how I have it now: [Link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/856/samplevb.png/)